# How to make the filter function on dates in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

'u' is a DataFrame containing ID = 1, 2, 3 .. and time= "2010-01-01", "2012-04-06", ..
ID and time have type string. I convert type of time' to 'Date'

```
u$time <- cast(u[[2]], "Date")
```

I now want the first time in u.

```
first <- first(u$time)
```

I now make a new time by adding 150 days to the first time

```
cluster<- first+150
```

I now want to make a subset. I want to have a new 'u' where the times are from the  first 150 days.

```
ucluster <- filter(u, u$time < cluster)
```

but this can't run in sparkR. I get this message "returnstatus==0 is not TRUE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that ucluster is a column of one item, rather than a date. If you take the first row and store its time in first, everything is working fine:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4),time=c("2010-01-01", "2012-04-06", "2010-04-12", "2012-04-09"))
u  <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,df)

u$time  <- cast(u[[2]], "Date")
first   <- take(u,1)$time
cluster <- first + 150

ucluster <- filter(u, u$time < cluster)

collect(ucluster)
```